# STPopup how to initialize in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Im playing with this [library](https://github.com/kevin0571/STPopup). It says that I have to init it with code

```
STPopupController *popupController = [[STPopupController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[ViewController new]];
[popupController presentInViewController:self];
```

I try to do this with following code (HelpersNear is name of UIViewController)

```
var popup = STPopupController(rootViewController: HelpersNear)
popup.presentInViewController(self)
```

but in response I get compile error which offers me to delete `rootViewController` from constructor. After I remove it, I get another error. [image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your `HelpersNear` view controller is not instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var popup = STPopupController(rootViewController: HelpersNear())
popup.presentInViewController(self)
```

For example:

```
class FooViewController: UIViewController {  
  let name: String

  init() {
    name = "Bar"
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)
  }

  required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is easy way to use this library in Swift.
Below I put example for BottomSheet style popup using STPopupController.

1. Create UIViewController or UITableViewController in Storyboard (you can use example done in Example Project (STPopupExample) of STPopup library available on github).
2. Set the view controller's storyboard id to f.ex.: `MultiselectionTableViewController`
3. To show this popup view use the following code:

   ```
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MultiselectionTableViewController") as! MultiselectionTableViewController
       vc.title = "Choose your options"
       vc.items = ["First element", "Second element", "Third element"]
       vc.delegate = self

       let popup = STPopupController(rootViewController: vc)
       popup.style = STPopupStyle.BottomSheet

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 

           popup.presentInViewController(self.parentViewController)
       })
   ```
4. It is important to show popup inside `dispatch_async` block. It prevents lags in showing new view controller.